# SAP Scripting Errors in Python

Tags: python, sap-gui

I'm new tho the community and relatively new to Python coding so please don't laugh too hard at my rudimentary question below. I am running SAP scripting and converting it to Python language which has been working well for the most part except one action I cannot seem to execute. I have pasted the code below.

I am trying to right click and select find which is represented in the code below. It generates the following error from this line **---> 58         session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem("&FIND")**

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (619, 'SAP Frontend Server', 'The control could not be found by id.', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfront.HLP', 393215, 0), None)

Has anyone encountered this before? Any suggestions... my other thought was to do the actions without right clicking but using positions but I don't know if that will produce the same result each time for different users. I appreciate your help.. total novice here :).

**Code to right click and select find from a variant table in SAP**

````
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectColumn("VARIANT")
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").pressColumnHeader("VARIANT") 
        #Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem("&FIND")```
````

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try with xxx.contextMenu() (Python needs a lot of brackets to work guiscripting ;) )

Keep us posted !